# Multiple masking with Multiple masks created from their original image with Google Engine

Tags: javascript

I have created series2 mask imageCollection from their original imageCollection series1. But the problem was the multiple masking failed with the following code. I used MODIS Terra version 6 clipped from a featurecollection, images with time period from 2013-12-1 to 2013-12-5. I want to mask the original images from the masks I created and get the cloud cover.
This is the code I used to create the cloud masks

```
var series2 = series1.map(function(image1){
return image1.select('sur_refl_b01').reproject('EPSG:4326', null,spatial_res)
.set('system:time_start', image1.get('system:time_start'))
.clip(rm_sh).gt(1200);
```

This is the code I used for multiple masking. This code was used to iterate the masking to the series1 imageCollection. But it does not iterate. It just performs only for the 1st image.

```
var time0 = reference.first().get('system:time_start');
var first = ee.List(ee.Image(0).set('system:time_start', time0).clip(rm_sh));
var cloud_masking = function(){
var series1list = series1.toList(100);
var series2list = series2.toList(100);
var l_masked = ee.Image((series1list).get(0));
var cloud_mask = ee.Image((series2list).get(0));
var cloud_img= l_masked.updateMask(cloud_mask).
 set('system:time_start', l_masked.get('system:time_start'));
return series1list.add(cloud_img);
};
 var cumulative = ee.ImageCollection(ee.List(series1.iterate(cloud_masking, first)));
Map.addLayer(cumulative,{min: 0, max: 32000},'cloud');
```

[image: Image description]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a changed code I have. And It works properly.(Thanks for Karan)

```
`var arr1 = [];
for (var i = 0;i<series1.size().getInfo();i++){
 var l_masked = ee.Image(series1list.get(i));
 var cloud_mask = ee.Image(series2list.get(i));
 var cloud_cover = l_masked.updateMask(cloud_mask)
   .set('system:time_start', l_masked.get('system:time_start'));
 Map.addLayer(cloud_cover,{min:0 , 
     max:32000},''+l_masked.getInfo().properties['system:index'])
 var c = cloud_cover.reduceRegion({reducer: ee.Reducer.count(), geometry: rm_sh });
 arr1[i]=c;   
 }
 print(arr1);`
```